# Visual Studio debugger does not stop on IE10 window close

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, debugging, web-applications

I'm working on a web application with VS2010 (using Windows 7) and usually in debug mode:
1. when I close the browser window, the debugger stops
2. when I stop the debugger, the browser window closes
Some time ago these stopped working.
Recently I updated my IE9 to IE10 and I suspect that this issue could be connected with IE10.
Any help?

Comment: Do you use threading? My guess is a thread stays alive. Try to see if the debugger can tell you which, then explicitly terminate it.

Comment: No, I don't use threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that in the "Browse With" menu of the web application there are two instances of Internet Explorer and when I tried to set to default one of them, always the same instance was set to default.
I guess that IE9 did not delete some registry data.
So, when I browsed my application several times with other browsers, the second instance of Internet Explorer disappeared and my problem stopped reproducing.

Now, when start debugging my VS2010 pops-up a message saying "Attaching the Script debugger of process '...' on machine '...' failed. A debugger is already attached". In Task Manager I see two instances of IE - one x64 and one x86...
I will see the questions on this topic.

Hope my post helps someone else.

Thank you, Daniel, for your attention.

Answer (score 7):

I use VS Ultimate 2012. Just tried and it worked:

Open browserlist dropdown in the toolbar (button with green triangle), click on "Browse With...". After some seconds browserlist window will be opened. Select "Internet Explorer" that is NOT default and remove it. Close window and try to debug.

If second "Internet Explorer" is still there try to select another browser and then select "Internet Explorer" again.

Hope it helps.